# Error about this lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++

This is my problem!!

```
for( i = 0; i <= MAX - 2; i++){
    for( j = i + 1; j <= MAX - 1; j++){
        if(stud[i].getEdad() < stud[j].getEdad()){
            temp=stud[i].getEdad();
            stud[i].getEdad() = stud[j].getEdad();
            stud[j].getEdad() = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is it on?

Comment: btw, what type does ``stud[i].getEdad()`` return? what is its function declaration?

Comment: Post the full code if it isn't too long

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 50
class moduleSupport{
 private:
     int edad;
     int status;
 public:
     int getStatus(){
        return status;
    }
     int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }
     void setStatus(int a){
        status = a;
    }
     void setEdad(int a){
        edad = a;
    }
};

Comment: `getEdad()` returns an `int` by value. That is, the return is an rvalue, and you can't assign a value to it. You need to return an lvalue reference. Search for "return by reference C++".

Comment: I don't know what to do , but thank you

Comment: @EdzelAbliter perhaps there is a ``setEdad()`` function?

Answer (score 1):

Source of problem I believe is

```
stud[i].getEdad() = stud[j].getEdad().
```

An lvalue (locator value) represents an object that occupies some identifiable location in memory (i.e. has an address). rvalues are defined by exclusion, by saying that every expression is either an lvalue or an rvalue. Therefore, from the above definition of lvalue, an rvalue is an expression that does not represent an object occupying some identifiable location in memory

With that said, an assignment expects an lvalue as its left operand i.e.

```cpp
//Here foo returns a reference i.e lvalue so ther's no problem in below code.
int& foo()
{
    return globalvar;
}

int main()
{
    foo() = 10;
    return 0;
}

//whereas following one will give you an error since return value is just a temporary object and you are assigning to it.
int foo()
{
    return globalvar;
}

int main()
{
    foo() = 10;
    return 0;
}
```